# saveSVGAsPNG | preserving transparency on copy image

Tags: javascript, svg, png

I'm happily using saveSVGAsPNG (https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng) which has saved me time and sanity. But my client tells me that when they copy the resulting PNG images and paste them into powerpoint, the transparent background turns black. (This doesn't happen on my version of powerpoint on my mac.)

I understand there are settings you can set within photoshop etc to stop this happening (http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00627_Transparent_areas_of_graphics_turn_black.htm). Does anyone know of setting changes one can make to saveSVGAsPNG function to achieve the same effect?

Thanks

Emma

Comment: I'm afraid the problem here is with Windows clipboard and there isn't much you can do. You could instruct the client to right-click, then save image as..., then import the image from disk to powerpoint and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to disable the right click copy option, to encourage/force users to use save as?

Comment: you could create a download button (or make the entire converted SVG a download link) that shows the browser dialog for saving a file. Here's an example I've googled: http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/5hnyf/ - the `downloadCanvas` function is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for displaying image on web.

```
service.getImage().subscribe(response => {
 let reader = new FileReader();
 reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
   imageData = reader.result;
   }, false);
 reader.readAsDataURL(response);
}
```

This may help you